# Using a object value in another object

Tags: javascript, object

Firstly, I have no idea if i've used the right terminology here, so a big apology up front. I'll do my best to explain what I'm trying to do.

**What I have**

I have an object that returns the following:

```js
  var upload = {
          created: "21/07/2017",
          name: "album photo name",
          progress:100,
          url:"www.url.com/photo.jpg"
        }
```

I'm trying to use the URL value in one of my objects to perform an update to a database

```js
  var myList = {
          albumtitle: title,
          albumDate: date,
          album_photo_url: upload.url
        }
```

When performing the update to the database, the console logs:

> ERror: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Firebase.update failed: First argument containers undefined in property 'album.jdslakjdlkas.sjdlkajsd.album_photo_url'

**Questions**
Is the syntax I'm using correct? When I remove the album_photo_url line, the other data uploads correctly. Or if I write:

```
album_photo_url:upload
```

Then everything uploads to the database with a nested node which includes the uploads progress, name, date and URL. How do I access the URL in my object reference?

Any help here would be massively appreciated.

**Edit**
Here's my full code segment:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
// import { AngularFire, AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2';
import { Upload } from './upload';
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable, FirebaseObjectObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import { AuthService } from '../../auth.service';


@Injectable()
export class UploadService {

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase, private authService: AuthService) { }

  private basePath: string = '/site_photo';

  uploads: FirebaseListObservable<Upload[]>;


  getUploads(query = {}) {
    this.uploads = this.db.list(this.basePath, {
      query: query
    });
    return this.uploads
  }




  submitForm(title: string, date: string, upload: Upload) {
    this.authService.user.subscribe(user => {
      if (user) {

        console.log(upload.url);

        // The User ID of the current user
        var userId = user.uid;


        // Data to be added to the 'Album' node
        var projectsDetails = {
          albumTitle: title,
          albumDate: reference,
          album_photo_url: upload.url
        }

        // Data to be added to the 'Album List' node
        var projectsList = {
        albumTitle: title,
          albumDate: reference,
          album_photo_url: upload.url
        }



        // Generate a new firebase key to be used for the Project, Project List and Project Member nodes
        var newPostKey = firebase.database().ref().child('album_list').push().key;

        // Create a reference to the firebase storage
        const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
        const uploadTask = storageRef.child('site_photo/' + user.uid + '/' + newPostKey + '/site_photo').put(upload.file);


        // Group the updates to the associated firebase nodes
        var updates = {};
        updates['/album/' + user.uid + '/' + newPostKey] = projectsDetails;
        updates['/album_list/' + user.uid + '/' + newPostKey] = projectsList;







        uploadTask.on(firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED,
          (snapshot) => {
            // upload in progress
            upload.progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100
          },
          (error) => {
            // upload failed
            console.log(error)
          },
          () => {
            // upload success
            upload.url = uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL
            upload.name = upload.file.name
            this.saveToRealtimeDatabase(updates);
          }
        );

      }

    });


  }

  private saveToRealtimeDatabase(updates) {    
    // Perform an atomic Multi-Path update
    return firebase.database().ref().update(updates);
  }


}
```

Comment: What? 
It's only javascript and object tags in your question. No mentioning about other technologies. But it's looks like database error message.

Comment: I didn't mention the other technologies here as i believe it's my syntax that's the issue, not the database. I need to maintain the format of the 'myList' object. I just need to know how to correctly assign the upload url value to 'album_photo_url:'. When I remove that line everything works fine, which is why i've pinpointed it to my incorrect syntax...I think :)

Comment: That is not a valid object and missing commas after properties.

Comment: it's not clear where the failure is been thrown. can a try to make a fiddle with sample code for debugging the procedure?

Comment: @Suresh, I've updated the code. That was an error on my typing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

upload object seems to be missing the url variable, before creating a new object check if "upload" actually has the url in it.

It's hard to give a better answer with limited code you've provided. Does both objects are in same scope?

[image]

Just from the clean console there is absolutely no issue in syntax from what you provided.

Comment: it's a promise error, so i think the scope can be different and it's a dependency injection problem in the active scope of where myList is been initialized

Comment: Thanks both. I've updated the post with my full post. MegaDammed, I think you're right. The upload URL isn't being defined until the 'upload success' check. upload.url = uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL

Comment: @MegaTron in that case if it is only sent once the data came through, you can create the object with an empty string initially and update that value in upload success scenario

Comment: ha, I literally just did that. Thanks MegaDammed. I needed to read that out loud for it to click and realise it was undefined to start with. If you add that comment to your answer, I'll update it. Appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myList = {
    albumtitle: title,
    albumDate: date
}

myList.album_photo_url = upload.url;
```

Comment: late binding is not a sollution for this problem. please read the question again

Comment: How is it not a solution?

Comment: `var myList = { album_photo_url: upload.url}` makes exactly the same than `myList.album_photo.url = upload.url` it's only late binding and not intial binding